# Howto encode/decode arbitrary data with OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, openssl, aes

I have a C++ application that has its own routines to send and receive data. I would like to use OpenSSL to apply AES encryption to parts of this data. Unfortunately I can't hand over the whole connection to OpenSSL like most examples do and I can't even give OpenSSL the socket to read the data from.

I would like to pass my data in and out as memory buffers and I also have the keys transmitted separately. Does anyone have an example how this can be done with the OpenSSL API ?

I have seen code that fiddles with the internal pointers and structures of OpenSSL, but was dependant on a certain OpenSSL version and I would very much like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually want to use the crypto library, which is part of OpenSSL. Here is an example of how to use it:

http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt

Comment: Where do I find the documentation for the EVP_* functions for AES ? The example uses EVP_aes_256_ecb() which doesn't appear in the EVP_* documentation at http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html

Comment: I'm afraid the documentation on the website is out-of-date. An updated version can be found here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_cipher_ctx_init.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at cryptlib http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/

The following is a snippet from the examples link at the cryptlib website:

```
CRYPT_SESSION cryptSession;

/* Create the session */
cryptCreateSession( &cryptSession, cryptUser, CRYPT_SESSION_SSL_SERVER );

/* Add the server key/certificate and activate the session */
cryptSetAttribute( cryptSession, CRYPT_SESSINFO_PRIVATEKEY, privateKey );
cryptSetAttribute( cryptSession, CRYPT_SESSINFO_ACTIVE, 1 );
```

Seems simple but for me it took some time (and is still taking some time) to learn how to do the stuff I want to with cryptlib. I think it would solve your issues! The source code is available and the DLL's have a C API. Give it a try. (Sounds like a commercial, but I have no connection with cryptlib except being a user of it).